# Endless looping solution for action trouble

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

### The goal

Stop an infinite loop generated by actions.

### The problem

I have a store application. The products are on categories and they can be marked as *offer*. There is a *left-side* menu to list the categories of my application (like *Clothing*, *Shoes*, *Caps*, etc.). One item of this menu is `Offers`, but `Offers` isn't a category, it is just a flag. Any item can be in the offerings "category", but a shoe can not be in caps.

If I access `myapp.com/Category/Shoes/`, only shoes will be displayed to me. If I access `myapp.com/Category/Daily-Offers/`, today's deal will be displayed to me — and offers can be shoes, caps, clothes.

As you can see, in the both cases (shoes or daily offers) the user will come across with `Category` route, but the controllers are different. Look at my `App_Start > RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Categories",
   url: "Category/{categoryName}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Products", 
                   action = "Category", 
                   categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional 
                 }
);
```

Now, my `ProductsController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Category(string categoryName = null)
{
    int? categoryId = 
       (categoryName != "Daily-Offers") ? 
       Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(categoryName, @"\d+").Value) : 
       (int?)null;

    if (categoryName == "Daily-Offers")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("DailyOffers", "Category");
    }
    else if (Regex.Match(categoryName, @"\d+").Success && String.Format("{0}-{1}",
             categoryId,
             CommodityHelpers.UppercaseFirst
             (CommodityHelpers.GenerateSlug
             (Categories.GetDetails((sbyte)categoryId).Category_Name))) 
             == categoryName)
    {
        [...]
        return View(Products.BuildListForHome(categoryId, null));
    }
    else
    {
        return View("404");
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is an "if" that points "Daily-Offers" for the correct controller.

The `DailyOffers` method, from `ProductsController`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DailyOffers()
{
    var productsList = Products.BuildOffersList();
    ViewBag.Title = String.Format("Today's deal ({0})", DateTime.Now);
    ViewBag.CategoryProductsQuantity = productsList.Count;
    ViewBag.CurrentCategory = "Daily-Offers";
    return View(productsList);
}
```

Finally, when I access `myapp.com/Category/Daily-Offers`, the response is an endless looping. *Yes, the reason is logical*, but what is the way to prevent this? Does someone has any idea of how to solve it?

### What I have already tried

I already decorate the `DailyOffers`' method with:

```
[ActionName("Daily-Offers")]
```

But no success — endless looping again.

### To emphasize

Daily offers ***isn't*** a category — it is a ***flag***. The application treats ***Offers*** like a category, but on database there is a column to the products called `onSale` that tells you whether an item is an offer or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your route table only knows about the `/Category/{categoryName}` so `/Category/Daily-Offers` is going to hit your `Category` action.

You can add a new mapping for the daily offers action above the existing category mapping:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "DailyOffers",
   url: "Category/Daily-Offers",
   defaults: new { controller = "Products", 
                   action = "DailyOffers"
                 }
);

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "Categories",
   url: "Category/{categoryName}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Products", 
                   action = "Category", 
                   categoryName = UrlParameter.Optional 
                 }
);
```

Comment: Mhmmm... How easy solution, huh? An apparent big problem was resolved with a simple solution. Thanks, man — it works! +1